# I'm trying to access the docusign API and I'm getting an error in authentication how to solve this?

Tags: java, jwt, docusignapi, bearer-token

When i'm trying to access the api, i'm getting the following error message:

**{
"errorCode": "PARTNER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED",
"message": "The specified Integrator Key was not found or is disabled. An Integrator key was not specified."
}**

I'm using the access token that returns from this URL: https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token, but the url address that the documentation asks to request the list of signed envelopes is this: https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/bf672cac-****-****-****-757e9b8ebfb3/envelopes.

If I change the beginning of the end-point domain to https://account-d.docusign.com/ I get the status 200 and an HTML, which doesn't say much about the error, follows the html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="LoginAppNext.App" lang="en" class="account-server">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" meta-description>
    <title>DocuSign</title>
    <link href="https://docucdn-a.akamaihd.net/olive/images/2.15.0/favicons/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon"
        type="image/x-icon">
    <base href="/">
    <link rel="canonical" href="https://account-d.docusign.com/" />




    <link href="/LoginAppNext/styles/olive/and/app?v=7_dKAUfFq_HQdBnGB4k7hYZKoOae-bgnT30ORlEXHEk1" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- 21.1.2.19210 DA2DFE5 ac4fea07-f999-49e8-b450-a9bd5aa45430 -->
    <!-- PAGE-TITLE DIRECTIVE MUST BE LAST INSIDE THE HEAD TAG -->
    <page-title></page-title>
</head>

<body class="site-content">

    <form name="fixtureForm">
        <input id="fixtureInput" value="illegible value that is returned in the request">
    </form>
<div ui-view></div>

        <!--[if (!IE)|(gt IE 8)]><!-->
        <script src="/LoginAppNext/core_via_npm?v=HmqVrseATw9A8eLx4-PxjAKYi3QSWgFzyC0R2L_sc9Q1"></script>


        <!--<![endif]-->
        <!--[if lte IE 8]>
      <link href="/LoginAppNext/styles/legacy?v=4PA642FFntoeJCbU9Xo8MtjFl47UpOhb1wGcStBQ1UU1" rel="stylesheet"/>

      <script src="/LoginAppNext/core_via_npm/legacy?v=k4d0Yt_N4blS8S0QrMQ8yybLJtbXex6uQ8SkokHHi_41"></script>


        <style type="text/css">
            /*
                Older browsers (IE8) may interpret the new tags as having an empty XML namespace
                when Angular attempts to generate them, so we need to deal with the default styling of those elements, too.
            */

            \:article,
            \:aside,
            \:details,
            \:figcaption,
            \:figure,
            \:footer,
            \:header,
            \:hgroup,
            \:main,
            \:nav,
            \:section,
            \:summary {
              display: block; }
        </style>
    <![endif]-->
        <script src="/LoginAppNext/templates?v=daF9DMXq4GIP_dsEt7fCPBYMN-A6Xk9bMZC4suEj0r01"></script>

        <script src="/Scripts/app?v=lfm-G_adZ-QhT3MeHhQWFFV_fQ6ENsg6BV4q01boB6M1"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Are you making sure the header has a key of "authorization", and the value has a prefix of Bearer before the token?

Comment: I can't say this, but can you tell me how to check?

Comment: How are you making the call? Through code or a tool like postman?

Comment: First by postman, and then I will use the code to obtain the token

Answer (score 0):

Its likely that you are not passing the Authorization header in your request. In your postman request please add this in the "headers" tab just under where you enter the resource uri, in the format of Key:Authorization Value: Bearer {AccessToken}

Please have a look at our postman collection that you can easily import to see how this works: https://github.com/docusign/postman-collections

Comment: This resource I used in the first attempt, but I suspect that it is generating wrong, because it generates an error saying: **Unresolved Variable
This variable is not defined in the active collection, environment or globals.** And now I don't know how to continue

Comment: You will need to fill in each variable in your enviornment or collections scope. You can learn more about variables [here](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/variables/)